# Sharepoint Central Administrator V3 cannot connect to the configuration server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a running portal application and it is integrated with sharepoint. Now we had to cloe the server for a new test portal. But after cloning the server, sharepoint stopped working.

the error is "Cannot connect to the configuration server". Of course we had to change the name of the computer. The server is windows server 2008 r2. I have changed the config files, regedit storages but nothing worked. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: 06/21/2012 17:34:02.56  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0A6C)                    0x0A94 Windows SharePoint Services    Database                       6f8a Critical Cannot connect to SQL Server. xxx\Microsoft##SSEE not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Change webconfig, and give new connection string name.